# dev_appserver.sh command not found

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have followed every instruction as given here: [Try Google App Engine Now](https://console.developers.google.com/start/appengine). Yet, at the step:

`dev_appserver.sh target/appengine-try-java-1.0`, after

`cd appengine-try-java
 mvn package`,

I get the error: `-bash: dev_appserver.sh: command not found`. I'm not sure what I'm missing here. I am not able to find the script file `dev_appserver.sh` and that's why it says `command not found` but how do I fix this?

Comment: Did you install the SDK? Does `/usr/local/bin/dev_appserver.py` work instead of `dev_appserver.sh`?

Comment: The command `gcloud` works. That means SDK is installed right? But using `/usr/local/bin/dev_appserver.py` didn't work either.

Comment: I get this: 

`$ gcloud version
Google Cloud SDK 0.9.35

bq 2.0.18
bq-nix 2.0.18
compute 2014.10.30
core 2014.11.03
core-nix 2014.10.20
dns 2014.10.30
gcutil 1.16.5
gcutil-nix 1.16.5
gsutil 4.6
gsutil-nix 4.6
sql 2014.10.30`

Anyone with any ideas? I have no idea where to begin.

Comment: I re-did the whole process mentioned in the OP and I found that I didn't get this "Follow the prompts to install the Java App Engine package" when I was installing. All I got was asking permissions to set rc files. Does this help in figuring out the problem?